# PHP Sample to Request and Download Bing Ads Report not working

Tags: php, ads, bing, sample

I'm really stucked on this so any help would be really useful!!

I've download the PHP Sample to Request and Download Bing Ads Report: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PHP-Sample-that-Shows-How-d817dfe5 and is not working for me. I've tried lots of things and don't know what to do now.

I'm using Ubuntu and got my SOAP installed, it's seems that Request Classes are not generated by SOAP, I paste what happens next:

$ php ReportingSample.php
To specify the report to generate, please enter the numeric value of the corresponding report. Otherwise, enter the ID of a previous download attempt.

1  - Account Performance Report

2  - Ad Performance Report

3  - Campaign Performance Report

4  - Keyword Performance Report

5  - Negative KW Conflict Report

6  - Search Query Report

Type (or 99 to end): 4

Enter a valid file name to write the report to. Do not include an extension.
test

The report will be written to /home/opascual/projects/bing/PHP/PhpReportingSample/ReportingSample/reports/test.zip.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'KeywordPerformanceReportRequest' not found in /home/opascual/projects/bing/PHP/PhpReportingSample/ReportingSample/ReportingSample.php on line 347

Thanks in advance!!

Oscar

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the Bing API PHP production classes from 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/PHP-Production-Classes-for-378b0d25